# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Trying to set foreign cookie

Tags: java, android, cookies, service, spreadsheet

I have a problem with SpreadSheetService getFeed. When I try to getFeed of the service receive an *IllegalArgumentException*

code in my main java class

```
SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("MyApp");
try{
    URL SPREADSHEET_URL = new URL("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oVOSFE8_LE4i8NjYDIX9gUGgdYDmOhqgcDI4HsqDQAo/edit?usp=sharing");
    SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_URL,SpreadsheetFeed.class);
    List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();
    if (spreadsheets.size() == 0){
        System.out.println("NO SPREADSHEET");
    }
} catch(IOException e){
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to access your drive doc and it seems you did not publish it to the web which the API requires.

So go into your sheet **File -> Publish To Web**

You can read more about the API [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#sheets_api_urls_visibilities_and_projections)

EDIT: Change your link to this

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1oVOSFE8_LE4i8NjYDIX9gUGgdYDmOhqgcDI4HsqDQAo/public/full
```

Apparently this is what you have to do with the api url

```
https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/**key**/public/full
                                                   ^ 
                                                 replace this with your sheet key
```

Comment: Ok I resolve problem. how did you change the link ?
which way did you use? thanks.

Comment: @mc_marad Look at the second link I provided in my answer. I replaced the key with the key from your sheet link.